# El constructor de mi clase no funciona

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy intentando implementar un TDA que utiliza listas de listas. A la hora de probarlo me di cuenta que había un error en el constructor. Este consiste en tomar un arreglo de tamaño n y almacenar los elementos en una lista que contiene sublistas de tamaño b. Imprimí algo distinto en cada linea para ver donde estaba el problema y me di cuenta que itera solo una vez, independiente del valor de n. El ciclo deja de funcionar una vez vuelve a entrar. Realmente no entiendo cual es el problema.
Esta es la clase:

```
class DeBlock{
  private:
    int cant_elems;
    tListadeListas L;
  public: 
    DeBlock(tElem* elems, int n, int b);
    ~DeBlock();
    int insert(int pos, tElem elem);
    tElem get_value(int pos);
    int length();
    void clear();
};
```

Y este el constructor:

```
DeBlock::DeBlock(tElem* elems, int n, int b) {
    int a = n / b;
    if (n % b != 0) {
        a += 1;
    }
    cant_elems = a;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        tLista Lista;
        for (int j = 0; j < b && i < n; j++) {
            tElem valor = elems[i];
            Lista.append(valor);
            i++;
        }
        L.append(Lista);
    }
}
```

Tanto tLista como tListadeListas son otros TDA's que tuve que implementar para poder hacer "DeBlock"

Answer (score -1):

Depende como hayas implementado tu clase `tListadeListas`, como hayas ingresado los datos, y como hayas impreso la información.

Pero te dejo un ejemplo de como hice lo que ocupas para que te des una idea y lo implementes con tus TDAs.

Defino una clase básica.

```
class TElem{
    public:
        int a;
};
```

Utilizo la TDA de Cpp llamada vector (Que en tu caso sería la Lista de Listas)

```
class DeBlock{
    int cant_elems;
    vector<vector<TElem>> L;
    
    public:
        DeBlock(TElem* elems, int n, int b);
        void printListas();
};
```

Creo las listas en el constructor.

```
DeBlock::DeBlock(TElem* elems, int n, int b) {
    int a = n / b;
    if (n % b != 0) {
        a += 1;
    }
    cant_elems = a;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        vector<TElem> Lista;
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            TElem valor = elems[i];
            Lista.push_back(valor);
            i++;
        }
        L.push_back(Lista);
    }
}
```

Imprimo de esta manera haciendo un loop entre cada grupo de listas:

```
void DeBlock::printListas(){
    for(int i=0; i<L.size(); i++){
        cout << "Lista: " << i << endl;
        for(int j=0; j<L[i].size(); j++){
            cout << L[i][j].a << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Y mi main lo utilizaría de esta manera:

```
int main()
{
    TElem tElems[10];
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        tElems[i].a = 10;
    }
    
    DeBlock deBlock(tElems, 10, 5);
    
    deBlock.printListas();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! implementé la función print pero no logra ejecutarse, el código se corta en la penúltima linea del constructor.  Imprimí algo distinto en cada linea del constructor y justo cuando sale del while es que deja de funcionar. Ya comprobé que los valores de a y n fueran correctos, puesto que al imprimirlos se muestra por pantalla los valores corrector.